# Python: Why is the variable I send to a function not the same as the variable it receives

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm a senior in high school working on my first project that uses lots of recursion, and I'm having an issue with passing a variable to a function. I feel like the issue isn't the recursion but something to do with functions that I don't know.

I call the function using

```
backOnTrack(maze, pos, findPath(maze, pos, path))
```

When I print pos before calling the function, it prints [0, 14]. And when I print pos at the start of backOnTrack it prints [2, 12].

findPath returns an array, nothing else, although pos is updated inside of it but not globally, yet the pos that is printed in backOnTrack is the same as it was at the end of findPath. I'll post my whole code below if anyone wants to go through all of it, sorry for poor formatting, still just learning.

```
import time
Matrix = [[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
          [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
          [0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]]
#Prints the maze
def printMaze(maze):
    print('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n')
    for x in maze:
        for y in x:
            if y==1:
                print('$', end='')
            elif y==2:
                print('X', end='')
            elif y==3:
                print('0', end='')
            else:
                print(' ', end='')
        print ('')
    time.sleep(.3)

#Used the found path to return move the player
def backOnTrack(maze, pos, path):
    print(pos)
    stillPath=True
    while(stillPath):
        path[pos[0]][pos[1]]=0
        #Sets the old current position to a visited position
        x=0
        while x<len(maze):
            y=0
            while y<len(maze[0]):
                if maze[x][y]==3 or maze[x][y]==4:
                    maze[x][y]=2
                y+=1
            x+=1
        #Sets current position
        maze[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 3
        printMaze(maze)
        #Checks to see if the square to the right of current position was marked on path[]
        if pos[1]+1<len(maze[0]) and path[pos[0]][pos[1]+1]==1:
            pos[1]+=1
        #Checks up
        elif pos[0]+1<len(maze) and path[pos[0]+1][pos[1]]==1:
            pos[0]+=1
        #Checks left
        elif pos[1]-1>=0 and path[pos[0]][pos[1]-1]==1:
            pos[1]-=1
        #Checks down
        elif pos[0]-1>=0 and path[pos[0]-1][pos[1]]==1:
            pos[0]-=1
        else:
            stillPath=False

#Once a dead end is reach this function returns to the nearest tile with a blank adjacent tile
def findPath(maze, pos, path):
    maze[pos[0]][pos[1]]=4
    #Checks if right is open
    if pos[1]+1<len(maze[0]) and maze[pos[0]][pos[1]+1]==0:
        return path
    #Checks if up is open
    elif pos[0]+1<len(maze) and maze[pos[0]+1][pos[1]]==0:
        return path
    #Checks if left is open
    elif pos[1]-1>=0 and maze[pos[0]][pos[1]-1]==0:
        return path
    #Checks if down is open
    elif pos[0]-1>=0 and maze[pos[0]-1][pos[1]]==0:
        return path
    #Checks right
    elif pos[1]+1<len(maze[0]) and maze[pos[0]][pos[1]+1]==2:
        path[pos[0]][pos[1]+1]=1
        pos[1]+=1
        return(findPath(maze, pos, path))
    #Checks up
    elif pos[0]+1<len(maze) and maze[pos[0]+1][pos[1]]==2:
        path[pos[0]+1][pos[1]]=1
        pos[0]+=1
        return (findPath(maze, pos, path))
    #Checks left
    elif pos[1]-1>=0 and maze[pos[0]][pos[1]-1]==2:
        path[pos[0]][pos[1]-1]=1
        pos[1]-=1
        return (findPath(maze, pos, path))
    #Checks down
    elif pos[0]-1>=0 and maze[pos[0]-1][pos[1]]==2:
        print('x')
        path[pos[0]-1][pos[1]]=1
        pos[0]-=1
        return (findPath(maze, pos, path))

#Moves the position checking to the right first then checking in a clockwise order
def movePos(maze,pos):
    continueOn=True
    while continueOn:
        #Generates a blank path
        path=[]
        for each in maze:
            aList=[]
            for x in each:
                aList.append(0)
            path.append(aList)
        #Sets the old current position to a visited position
        x=0
        while x<len(maze):
            y=0
            while y<len(maze[0]):
                if maze[x][y]==3:
                    maze[x][y]=2
                y+=1
            x+=1

        maze[pos[0]][pos[1]]=3
        printMaze(maze)
        #Set's the ending point of the maze
        endPos = [len(maze)-1, len(maze[0])-1]
        #Checks to see if the end of the maze has been reached
        if pos == endPos:
            return True
        #Checks right, ensures it's not outside of the bounds of the maze and is not a wall or previously visited square
        if pos[1]+1<len(maze[0]) and maze[pos[0]][pos[1]+1]==0:
            pos[1]+=1
            movePos(maze,pos)
        #Checks up
        elif pos[0]+1<len(maze) and maze[pos[0]+1][pos[1]]==0:
            pos[0]+=1
            movePos(maze,pos)
        #Checks left
        elif pos[1]-1>=0 and maze[pos[0]][pos[1]-1]==0:
            pos[1]-=1
            movePos(maze,pos)
        #Checks down
        elif pos[0]-1>=0 and maze[pos[0]-1][pos[1]]==0:
            pos[0]-=1
            movePos(maze,pos)
        else:
            print(pos)
            backOnTrack(maze, pos, findPath(maze, pos, path))


movePos(Matrix, [0,0])
```

Comment: Please edit your code down to a [mcve].

Comment: You might find that your findPath function is changing the `pos` value - remember in python ALL varibales are passed as an object - and also when you call `backOnTrack` - python will call  Findpath first.

Comment: python sends to function reference to `pos`, not duplicate it - so you modify oryginal object.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware that it was the original object that is passed. Not sure how to mark question as answered, but thank you!

Comment: I have created a formal answer - you can mark that as accepted - which will close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `findPath` function is changing the pos value - remember in python ALL variables are passed as an object. When when you call `backOnTrack` - python has to call `findpath` first.

If you want, you can verify this by putting the return of `findPath` into a temp variable - and checking the value of pos, before you call `backOnTrack`.

If you are used to C or similar, you are probably expecting Call by Value - but in Python everything is effectively Call by Reference: even in C though since pos is an array, this would be always passed by reference.

Comment: @b-allio - if this answer is correct (and I think it is) you should see a tick mark near it so that you can accept this.

Comment: "in Python everything is effectively Call by Reference" - no, it's not. In call by reference, `def f(x): x = 5` would actually have an effect when you do `x = 6; f(x)`.

Comment: @user2357112 it does when x is mutable.  When x isn't mutable (e.g. A string or an integer or float - then the example you give doesn't have an effect.)

Comment: No, if it worked like call by reference when x is mutable, then `def f(x): x = [5]` would actually have an effect when you do `x = [6]; f(x)`.

Comment: @user2367112 I think that you might be right - but the OPs issue was he was expecting Call by Value - and that isn't what Python does. It probably should be Call by Object - but I am not sure if there is a. Correct term for if.